# proving the divisibility of a fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

Given a fibonacci sequence with $F(0)=7, F(1)=11, F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$. How to prove that $F(n)$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $n-2$ is divisible by $4$.

The proof I can think of is to get the general term formula of $F$ then prove the divisibility. Does anyone have better methods?

Comment: Look at the sequence $g(n) = F(n) \bmod 3$. You could also use things you know about the Lucas sequence, since $F(n) = L_{n+4}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

First prove 
$$F(n+4)\equiv -F(n)\mod 3.$$
This is indeed easy:
\begin{align}
F(n+4)&\equiv F(n+3)+F(n+2)=2F(n+2)+F(n+1)\\
&\equiv -F(n+2)+F(n+1)=-F(n+1)-F(n)+F(n+1)=-F(n)
\end{align}
Now consider the $4$ first values modulo $3$:
$$F(0)\equiv 1,\quad F(1)\equiv-1, \quad F(2) \equiv 0,\quad F(3)\equiv-1.$$
Thus, for all $k\in\mathbf N$, F(2+4k)\equiv\pm F(2)=0$.

*Remark:* it is easy to check that $F(n)\bmod3$ is periodic and has period $8$. The period is:
$$1,-1,0,-1,-1,1,0,1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$n=2$ it is true, you have to show the result for $n=4k+2$.

Let's do it recursively. Suppose that $g(n)=F(n)$ mod $3$ is $0$ mod $3$.

$g(n+1)=g(n-1)+g(n)=g(n-1)$, $g(n+2)=g(n+1)+g(n)=g(n-1)$, $g(n+3)=g(n+2)+g(n+1)=2g(n-1)$, $g(n+4)=g(n+3)+g(n+2)=3g(n-1)=0$.

If $n\neq 2$ mod 4. Show recursively that $g(n)\neq 0$ as above.